# Cube's edges in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have drawn a cube in OpenGl to use it as skybox.
I'm using a single texture image and I use the UV coordinates to locate the 6 faces in the right positions.
I send the texture with the following code:

```
//------------------------------------Luminance--------------------------------------------------------------
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, m_width);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturePointer[0]);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, m_width, m_height, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_uYdata);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


//--------------------------------------U component------------------------------------------------------------
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, m_uvWidth);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturePointer[1]);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, m_uvWidth, m_uvHeight, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_uUdata);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

//------------------------------------- V component-------------------------------------------------------------
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturePointer[2]);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, m_uvWidth, m_uvHeight, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_uVdata);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

I can't remove the white edges between the faces of the cube, see the picture below:

[image: screenshot]

`GL_NEAREST` remove the problem but the quality of the image is lower,
how can I use `GL_LINEAR` and remove this effect?

**Edit:**

The cube is created using the following Tutorial:
[Model loading](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/)

Considering that the texture is made by six faces stitched in columns.
The actual Blender object is:

```
# Blender v2.77 (sub 0) OBJ File: 'demo_cube.blend'
# www.blender.org
o Cube
v  1.000000  -1.000000 -1.000000
v  1.0000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000  -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000  -1.000000 -1.000000
v  1.000000   1.000000 -1.000000
v  1.0000000  1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000   1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000   1.000000 -1.000000
vt 0.833333333 0.0000
vt 0.666666666 1.0000
vt 0.833333333 1.0000
vt 0.833333333 0.0000
vt 1.000000000 1.0000
vt 1.000000000 0.0000
vt 0.333333333 1.0000
vt 0.500000000 0.0000
vt 0.333333333 0.0000
vt 0.500000000 1.0000
vt 0.666666666 0.0000
vt 0.500000000 0.0000
vt 0.000000000 0.0000
vt 0.166666666 1.0000
vt 0.166666666 0.0000
vt 0.333333333 0.0000
vt 0.166666666 1.0000
vt 0.333333333 1.0000
vt 0.666666666 0.0000
vt 0.833333333 1.0000
vt 0.500000000 1.0000
vt 0.666666666 1.0000
vt 0.000000000 1.0000
vt 0.166666666 0.0000
s off
f 2/1 4/2 1/3
f 8/4 6/5 5/6
f 5/7 2/8 1/9
f 6/10 3/11 2/12
f 3/13 8/14 4/15
f 1/16 8/17 5/18
f 2/1 3/19 4/2
f 8/4 7/20 6/5
f 5/7 6/21 2/8
f 6/10 7/22 3/11
f 3/13 7/23 8/14
f 1/16 4/24 8/17
//44 and 47
```

The fragment shader is:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 oTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D yChannel;
uniform sampler2D uChannel;
uniform sampler2D vChannel;



out vec4 color;


const vec3 offset = vec3(0.0625, 0.5, 0.5);
const mat3 coef = mat3(
        1.164,  0.0,          1.793,
        1.164, -0.213, -0.533,
        1.164,  2.112,   0.0
    );

void main()
{ 
    vec2 nTexCoord = vec2(oTexCoord.x, 1.0 - oTexCoord.y);

    vec4 Tcolor = vec4(1.0);

    if(oTexCoord.y <1  && oTexCoord.y > 0.0) {
        if(oTexCoord.x < 1  && oTexCoord.x > 0.0) {

            vec3 yuv = vec3(
                    texture(yChannel, nTexCoord).r,
                    texture(uChannel, nTexCoord).r,
                    texture(vChannel, nTexCoord).r
                ) - offset;
            vec3 rgb = yuv * coef;

            Tcolor = vec4(rgb, 1.0);            
        }
    }

    color = Tcolor;

}
```

Comment: Did you check that your textures do not have any 1px border with white/transparent pixels or anything of the sort?

Comment: This kind of rendering error is related to the face geometry not aligning correctly at the edges. I am not clear on what you mean by "I'm using a single texture image and I use the UV coordinates to locate the 6 faces in the right positions." - if you mean you are positioning the vertexes with a texture, this might have to do with image format precision.

Comment: Since `GL_NEAREST` removes the problems, it is likely not a result of incorrectly aligned geometry. The given approach seems odd, however. I don't understand why you're storing uvs in a texture. Perhaps you could explain further your approach or add your shader code.

Comment: @Mr_Pouet : I checked the texture and seems do not have any white/transparent border, I have the same issue with different texture content.

Comment: @William Kappler: I've edited the question, then you can see the related geometry. May be, can be a problem of  format precision, but up to now I did some try and the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [cubemaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_mapping) and [`GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/seamless_cube_map.txt):

> Although it is unlikely that the generated ( s t ) coordinate lies    significantly outside the determined cube map face, it is often the    case that the locations of the individual elements required during a    linear sampling do not lie within the determined face, and their coordinates will therefore be modified by the selected clamping and wrapping rules. **This often has the effect of producing seams or other discontinuities in the sampled texture.**
>
> This extension allows implementations to take samples from adjacent cube map faces, providing the ability to create seamless cube maps.

(emph. mine).

To use it, first check that you indeed have that extension (this depends on your platform and on which toolkit is eventually helping you into accessing OpenGL), then just write

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS);
```

to enable it (globally).

Comment: The OP is not using cubemaps, so this won't help.

Comment: Then OP should use cubemaps too and enable seamless filtering.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use cubemaps because the function glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X,......) is too slow and my app changes the texture in real time.
The use of a single texture mapped with UV coordinates is a good choice if the purpose is send the texture to the GPU multiple times per second.

Comment: To be honest I can't quite understand why uploading 2D textures would be faster than uploading cubemap faces... what does a profiler say?

Comment: Basically, before this approach I've created the cube usign Cubemap and it was really slow because of the multiple accesses (6 times 3 color channels) to the function glTexImage2D().
Then I've decided to use just one single texture which use glTexImage2D() just one time per color channel.
I've used the same texture for both the cubes and is notable that the performance of the second approach is much better.

Comment: So for each face you upload 3 textures, one texture per channel, for a total of 18 textures for the entire cube?

Comment: Exactly, unless you have rgb textures. In that case should be fast enough, but I didn't tried because I don't want to use the cpu to convert in rgb.

Comment: Well, I still can't understand why uploading them as cubemap faces would be so slower. Please profile your code...